# where to find a list of configurable capabilities of azure cosmos db account?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to enable server side retry in a cosmos db (v4.0) account features. It can be easily done via az cli and azure portal. However, I am not sure how to do it via ARM template, as I do not know what the list of capabilities are allowed values when configuring capabilities.
Alternatively, can this be done using the old powershell module AzureRM (not az module)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable this feature, add the following JSON in the `capabilities` node in your ARM template:

```
{
    "name": "DisableRateLimitingResponses"
}
```

so your capabilities node would look something like:

```
"capabilities": [
    {
        "name": "EnableMongo"
    },
    {
        "name": "DisableRateLimitingResponses"
    }
],
```

To have this feature disabled, do not include the above mentioned JSON in your `capabilities` node.

Comment: Here is the link to the ARM documentation as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/2021-10-15/database-accounts/create-or-update. That particular capability name is just not documented there.

Comment: @juunas - Thanks! I also looked at the documentation first but couldn't find the details. Ended up creating a new account and checked the template :D.

Comment: Yeah, you can often check F12 tools Network tab to see what Azure Portal does. It typically uses the same APIs any way.